# Kafka Streams Architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am hoping to clarify a few ideas on Kafka Streams from an architectural standpoint.

I understand the stream processing and data enrichment uses, and that the data can be reused by other applications if pushed back into Kafka, but what is the correct implementation of a Streams Application?

My initial thoughts would be to create an application that pulls in a table, joins it to a stream, and then fires off an event for each entry rather than pushing it back into Kafka. If multiple services use this data, then each would materialize their own table, right?

And I haven't implemented a test application yet, which may answer some of these questions, but I think is a good place for planning. Basically, where should the event be triggered, in the streaming app or in a separate consumer app?

Comment: Kafka Streams has a `forEach` action, but I think it depends if other apps also want to act on the same data and would do so from a plain consumer

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking @cricket_007, I've been looking at the demos and docs but was curious if there was something I was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My initial thoughts would be to create an application that pulls in a table, joins it to a stream, and then fires off an event for each entry rather than pushing it back into Kafka.

In an event-driven architecture, where would the application send the events to (and how), if you think that Kafka topics shouldn't be the destination for sharing the events with other apps? Do you have other preferences?

> If multiple services use this data, then each would materialize their own table, right?

Yes, that is one option.

Another option is to use the [interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) feature in KStreams (aka queryable state), which allows your first application to expose its tables and state stores to other applications directly (e.g., via a REST API). Other apps would then not need to materialize their own tables. However, an architectural downside is that you have now a direct coupling between your first app and any other downstream applications through request-response communication. While this pattern of direct inter-service communication is popular for a microservices architecture, a compelling alternative is to not use direct communication but instead let microservices/apps communicate indirectly with each other via Kafka (i.e., to use the previous option).

> Basically, where should the event be triggered, in the streaming app or in a separate consumer app?

This is a matter of preference, see above. To inform your thinking you may want to read the 4-part mini series about event-driven architectures with Kafka: https://www.confluent.io/blog/journey-to-event-driven-part-1-why-event-first-thinking-changes-everything (disclaimer: this blog series was written by a colleague of mine).